# SparkSession and context confusion

Tags: python, apache-spark, save, apache-spark-mllib

I have a pyspark 2.0.0 script with the following session defined:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark") \
    .master("local[*]")\
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

I trained a random forest model and I want to save it. Therefore I am calling the following method:

```
model_rf.save( spark, "/home/Desktop")
```

but it throws the following compilation error:

```
TypeError: sc should be a SparkContext, got type <class 'pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession'>
```

when I define a Spark context, like so:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext()
model_rf.save( sc, "/home/Desktop")
```

I am getting the error:

```
Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=Python Spark, master=local[*]) created by getOrCreate at <ipython-input-1-c5f83810f880>:24
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `spark.sparkContext`(`SparkSession` object will have `sparkContext`)

```
model_rf.save( spark.sparkContext, "/home/Desktop")
```